# php Spout excel .xlsx writer make all cells TEXT

Tags: php, excel

I am using [spout](https://github.com/box/spout) and am trying to figure out how to make all cells written in text format and NOT general. The reason being is if a user edits a cell I want it to be exactly as the typed and NOT have excel guess what it is. (Converting 10% --> 10% as a PERCENT; when I read this back it is .1 and not 10%)

in [phpExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com) I am able to do:

```
PHPExcel_Cell::setValueBinder(new TextValueBinder());

class TextValueBinder implements PHPExcel_Cell_IValueBinder
{
    public function bindValue(PHPExcel_Cell $cell, $value = null) 
    {
        $cell->setValueExplicit($value, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
        return true;
    }
}
```

to force all cells as text.

Is there a way to do this in spout (I couldn't find in docs)? I like spout better because it is faster and uses less memory.

Even if I have to come up with a crazy hack; I am all for it.

Comment: no about your library, but in excel itself you can force a cell to be text only with no translation/formatting by prepending a `'`

Comment: The `'` seems to show up in the cell. Is there a way to NOT do this? Also is there some other library I can use or somehow modify spout to achieve what I want without losing performance?

Comment: Or is there a way to detect when READING a cell if it is a percentage cell format?

Comment: There is currently no way to do that unfortunately. But you should open an issue and hopefully someone will add this for you. Or you can try to add it yourself :)